# Что нужно написать в аргументы функции

Tags: c++

> Многочлены представляются в памяти ЭВМ целым числом n-степенью многочлена и массивом коэффициентов a[0],a[1]...,a[n].
> Составить функцию для вычисления коэффициентов многочлена - cуммы двух других многочленов. Функция возвращает степень многочлена - cуммы.
> int polysum(int n, double *a,int m, double *b, double *res );

```
double polysum(int n, double* a, int m, double* b, double* res)
{
    int nn = n;
    if (nn < m) { nn = m; }
    for (int i = 0; i <= nn; i++)
    {
        res[i] = 0;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        res[i] = a[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= m; i++)
    {
        res[i] += b[i];
    }
    return (nn);
}
int main()
{
    polysum();
}
```

Comment: И что не понятно Вам? У вас в вопросе правильный прототип метода, возвращающий ```int```, а в коде возвращается ```double```.

Answer (score 2):

Примерно так, я полагаю...

```
int polysum(int n, double* a, int m, double* b, double* res)
...

int main()
{
    double a[] = {1,2,3};
    double b[] = {4,5,6,7};
    double c[10];

    int n = polysum(3,a,4,b,c);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) cout << c[i] << "  ";
}
```